# Sometimes, jQuery only updates elements on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning javascript by creating a program which requests an API and dispays various properties (price in this example) to html. I have a few questions about my code and some problems I've been facing.

1). I have a bunch of `$.getJSON` functions corresponding to each value that I want to retrieve. I put them all in a a single 2 min. timer. When the page FIRST loads, however, some of the html elements fail to load at all. But if I refresh the page, they sometimes do load. If I refresh again, they might not load at all again. Every time I refresh, there's like a 10% chance of that particular function not inserting the content in the element. If it does load and I leave the page open, it will correctly function (update its value and html element every 2 mins and add/remove the green and red classes). If it doesn't load and I leave the page open, it will correctly function in 2 mins when the 2nd api request is made. I have already tested that the variables have some value (are not null) before and after each `$('#price').text('$' + price);`.

Here's an example of a function that does that:

```
var tempPrice;
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1200000);
myTimer();

function myTimer() {
  $.getJSON(link, function (json) {
    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
      if (value.id == "price") {
        var price = value.price_eur;
        if (!tempPrice) {
          $('#price').text('$' + price);
          tempPrice = parseFloat(price);
        }
        if (parseFloat(price) !== tempPrice) {
          $('#price').text('$' + price).removeClass();
          if (parseFloat(price) > tempPrice) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              $('#price').addClass("green");
            }, 1);
          } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
              $('#price').addClass("red");
            }, 1);
          }
          tempPrice = parseFloat(price);
        }
      }
    });
  });
  // Many more $.getJSON functions below...
}
```

If I run this function alone on either jsfiddle or my dev server (flask), it works fine. It only breaks down when I use it in conjunction with more api requests. If I remember correctly, I didn't have this problem before when I used to have a separate timer for each `$.getJSON` function and put each in its own `<script>` tag directly in html.

2) I know I can loop through the json instead of using `$.each`. How else can I improve the code?

Comment: your question is unclear, find the error and update your question or post your actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1

As for the problem you're having with the inconsistent behavior of the initial page loading, it's because you are executing JavaScript before giving the browser the time to load the page fully first. You can solve this simply by waiting for the page the load, and then executing your code.

Example in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Page is loaded, execute code...
});
```

## 2

To help you improve the way you're handling the supplied JSON data, a sample of the data would be useful.

Comment: Where exactly would that go in my example code? Just after defining the global variables? Because I've tried putting it in various places and now the javascript doesn't execute at all. I'm getting `ReferenceError: myTimer is not defined`

Comment: Try leaving everything in your code just as you posted here, except for when you call `myTimer()` function. You should call the timer function when the page has been loaded.